# Found index.php in files folder and all its subfolders? Anyone know what type of exploit is this?

Tags: security

I'm cleaning up my drupal installations and i found in the files folder there was an index.php file and all its subfolders. 
screenshot: 
[image]

I still dont know what kind of exploit was done to get all these files in here. Anyone had something similar or know what this is?

Comment: If you have sufficient reputation, you should add your picture directly to this site; that way, in the future, even if the third-party image host goes down/changes/etc. your picture will still be available to future users of this site.

Comment: If you would like, we can move this to a more appropriate sister site.  If so, just flag for moderator attention, and use a custom reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just an additional note, this looks like it could have been caused by the FCKEditor / CKEditor arbitrary file upload bug.

If using one of those WYSIWYGs, check this advisory:

http://drupal.org/node/1482528

and upgrade to latest

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a very dangerous exploit - they're basically able to arbitrarily pass commands through the request string ($cvjuec) and have them executed, or even write out files from the ($oktv) request string. I would suspect given the date of the attack, that the damage is already done or it was unsuccessful and they moved on. I looked for examples of this script but it may be using randomized variable names to avoid automatic detection.

Few suggestions (assuming this is a Linux system?)

- Run a rootkit scanner on your system, ex: http://www.rootkit.nl/projects/rootkit_hunter.html and follow instructions.
- Enable php open_basedir restrictions for this site (and others on this box?) to prevent your compromised php process from being able to write below the document root and compromising server-level files
- Check the logs for this site and see if you have a record of these attack vectors. I.e. look for urls that reference */sites/default/files/styles/index.php?cvjuec=*, or some of the other strings referenced in the above script to see if there is a record of what kinds of files they tried to install.
- Secure the permissions on your drupal folders following the [instructions in the documentation](http://drupal.org/node/244924) to prevent unauthorized users from writing to the folder with executable permissions
- Is this a multi-site server? Are there other sites on the server that could have been compromised and allow the user to write to these folders? I've had multi-site servers before where an exploit in on non-drupal site allowed attacks on unsecure drupal sites.
- Obviously should take a look at your modules and run any necessary Drupal security updates. [Security review module](http://drupal.org/project/security_review) can give you some tips for securing Drupal sites.

Unfortunately, you're probably in clean-up / recovery mode at this point, just trying to stop the bleeding. Best case scenario is that the attacker wasn't able to install anything sophisticated enough to damage the rest of the box (perhaps because open_basedir restrictions or PHP safe mode was already in place)  and this is as far as they got. If you do detect rootkits and other tools, they may have more control of your box than you can tell and moving to a new environment may be the best option.

Comment: i'm trying to grep for all these files by finding something in common with them.